# How to Create Colored Text Boxes with DIFFERENT colors using "\leftbar" command?

Tags: color, boxes

I am using the following code to generate a Colored Box in Latex:

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]%
{%
        \def\FrameCommand%
        {%                  
             \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{Lavender!25}%
        }%
        \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\leftbar
\textbf<\textbf{Data Type}> <\textbf{Array Name}> \textbf{[RowSize]  [ColumnSize]}; 
\endleftbar
```

The **Settings** for the colored box are fixed before: "`\begin{document}`".

Everytime, I draw a box using "`\leftbar`" "`\endleftbar`" -- it is always of the same color I mentioned in the Settings above.

But I want to get Boxes with **Different Colors** (Rest of the settings same as above).

It seems that "`\leftbar`" don't take the "color" as an Argument.

Can anybody please guide me on how to generate boxes with Different colors using "`\leftbar`"?

Comment: If you are interested in typesetting code, the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an argument for the color in the (re)definition of `leftbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[2][\hsize]%
{%
        \def\FrameCommand%
        {%                  
             \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{#2}%
        }%
        \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}{green!25}
\textbf<\textbf{Data Type}> <\textbf{Array Name}> \textbf{[RowSize]  [ColumnSize]}; 
\end{leftbar}

\begin{leftbar}{red!25}
\textbf<\textbf{Data Type}> <\textbf{Array Name}> \textbf{[RowSize]  [ColumnSize]}; 
\end{leftbar}

\begin{leftbar}{olive!25}
\textbf<\textbf{Data Type}> <\textbf{Array Name}> \textbf{[RowSize]  [ColumnSize]}; 
\end{leftbar}

\end{document}
```

[image]